# About the grammar of「寝ぐらに」

Tags: grammar

> まさか、寝ぐらにしてるのか？

What I don't know is the phrase '**寝ぐら**'. I guessed it is a grammatical clause but the search came up with no optimistic result.

However, with the search engine, I found that the Japaneses used it very often in forums and blogs, such as '**寝ぐらになる**'.

Can anyone tell me the meaning and the grammar behind it, thanks.

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AD%E3%81%90%E3%82%89

Answer (score 7, accepted):

寝ぐら is a nonstandard writing form of the word [ねぐら (塒)](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/169871/meaning/m0u/), which means bird's *roost*, and by extension, animal *den* or *lair*, and also in the way these English words could describe that of human.

> 寝ぐらにしてる = 塒にしている *be using as one's sleeping spot*

Some Japanese words that can be decomposed into multiple units, even if they have kanji as a whole, are occasionally written in combination of kanji that represent a part of the word.

> 卵【たまご】：玉【たま】子【ご】
>
> 偏【かたよ】り：片【かた】寄【よ】り
>
> 邪【よこしま】：横【よこ】しま

Sometimes it could be helpful to search an unknown wordform in all hiragana to find the word you want.